# Issues installing Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

built a new machine and want turn it into a Ubuntu sever (currently installing desktop version for testing).  I was able to install Ubuntu 18.04 but I was missing a driver for my Wifi built into my motherboard (intel wifi 6 ax200).  I decided since this is a recent build, I may need to install Ubuntu 19.10 to have the latest support for my drivers and hardware.  When I upgraded to 19.04, I still had no wifi card detected.  I then upgraded to 19.10 because, why not? Now I can't launch Ubuntu on system restart.  I can select Ubuntu in the Grub Menu and it just boots to a screen of text.

https://media.giphy.com/media/Y1vGFcBW5QTDYjvtW5/giphy.gif

I also noticed this issue when I tired to install 19.10 or 19.04 from a USB. I disabled secure boot in my bois and tried adding nomodeset in the grubmenu linux command before launch with no luck.

System is:

- Threadripper 3960X
- [RX40 AORUS MASTER (rev. 1.0)](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/TRX40-AORUS-MASTER-rev-10#kf)
- 2x 2080 ti - Only one is in the system now
- 64 GB of ram
- 1200w

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `mce=off` at the end of the kernel command inside grub. Thanks for all the help though!

More information on my issue was found here https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Linux-Boot-Threadripper-Zen2MCE